# Is this answer a copyright violation?

Tags: discussion, copyright

[This answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/796/why-are-onions-dangerous-for-my-cat-or-dog/797#797) has most of its content come from a single source. Which is attributed, but the content is not released on CC (Attribution).  Another user has placed a comment about the volume of copy and paste content, and I had added a follow up with a copyright concern.  Those comments have been removed and the work has not been edited to remove or limit the content.

In my opinion there is answer as is, is copyright issue. The removed comment indicates at least one person disagrees.  So I would like to open it for community debate. Does the single answer to the question [Are onions dangerous for my cat or dog and why?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/796/why-are-onions-dangerous-for-my-cat-or-dog) it's current state, clearly or questionably violate the copyright of the original author?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should we be doing with answers that are a series of quotes?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/437/what-should-we-be-doing-with-answers-that-are-a-series-of-quotes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of answers are we looking for?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-kind-of-answers-are-we-looking-for)

Answer (score 5):

No, the author of the post is supplementing their own words with facts from three publications, all of which we can most likely consider *fair use*. I don't think there's anything to worry about, and we're here to handle any issues surrounding copyright that might come up *on any site*, *for any post*.

Please, don't concern yourself with copyright law beyond making sure that:

- Proper attribution is provided
- It's made clear what the author's own words are, and what is being cited

This is no different than if they used content from another answer on the site. If you see wholesale copying (as in an *entire* post is just a copy / paste of something someone else published) or something else that looks like plagiarism, please flag it for moderator attention so that we (and soon, your pro-tem moderators) can look into it.

Meta is not the best place to hold a discussion to see if something does, or does not violate copyright law - none of us are lawyers. In the unlikely event that one of the cited publishers takes issue with the post, there are clear channels posted at the bottom of every page telling folks how to get in touch with us.

Comment: Here, copyright law is pretty simple - don't be a crank by copying other people's work without credit, make sure the majority of your answers are you own words and let us handle the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

Material does not need to be licensed under CC to be cited.

Australia has some of the strictest copyright laws, so it's safe to use this guide as a reference. This covers our national and international copyright laws.

To address your question (as the author of the post you cited)

> This answer has most of its content come from a single source

I have cited three sources, quoted from one.

> Which is attributed,

complying with copyright laws

> but the content is not released on CC (Attribution)

Material does not need to be licensed under CC to be cited.

> Another user has placed a comment about the volume of copy and paste
>   content,

Not true, this link gives an extended overview of the other person and the content.

> and I had added a follow up with a copyright concern.

Which was rebuked as being an uncalled for concern.

> Those comments have been removed

As they were flagged by me as redundant.

> and the work has not been edited to
>   remove or limit the content.

The work was edited to improve the readability of the answer. There is no need remove or limit the content.

> In my opinion there is answer as is, is copyright issue.

An opinion founded on a lack of knowledge of copyright law (I have studied copyright law and the internet in tertiary studies I completed this year A Certificate IV in Web Based Technologies)

> The removed comment indicates at least one person disagrees.

Another faulty assumption, the removed content indicates a moderator saw fit to remove it as obsolete.

> So I would like to open it for community debate.

This is the very thing I have been hitting my head against a wall with frustration. Some things are not open to debate, It is a matter of law, which is factual and not open to debate.

> Does the single answer to the question Why are onions dangerous for
>   my cat or dog? it's current state, clearly or questionably violate the
>   copyright of the original author?

**clearly or questionably violate the
 copyright of the original author?**

This poorly worded and faulty assumption, is presumptuous and insulting. There is no room within this question to account for the possibility that there is no copyright infringement.

[Australian Guide to Legal Citation](http://www.law.unimelb.edu.au/files/dmfile/FinalOnlinePDF-2012Reprint.pdf)